# Prevent vector from making all instances of class the same

Tags: c++, vector

Here is the struct of which I need to create a vector of:

```
/*
    Structure of a delegate, many expected*/
    struct delegate {
        const char * title;
        const char * name;
        const char * role;
        const char * group;

        delegate(const char * a, const char * b, const char * c, const char * d)
            : title(a),name(b),role(c),group(d)
        {}
    };
```

The issue is that in the code I will present below, even though different sets of data are correctly collected and can be constructed into objects of types delegate, the vector always ends up with all its instances being the same object, however while debugging it is made evident the data given to construct the objects in the vector are different, so why is this so?
The code:

```
    std::vector <delegate> delegates;
    ss << "SELECT Title,FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,Role,PartyId FROM Attendee WHERE eventId = ?", use(eventId), now;
    Poco::Data::RecordSet RecordSet(ss);
    ss.reset(*db_session);
    for (auto& record : RecordSet) {
        std::string result;
        delTitle = record.get(0).toString();
        delName = record.get(1).toString();
        delName.append(" ");
        delName.append(record.get(2).toString());
        delName.append(" ");
        delName.append(record.get(3).toString());
        delRole = record.get(4).toString();
        partyId = record.get(5).toString();
        ss << "SELECT '1' FROM Party WHERE Id = ?", into(result), use(partyId);
        ss.reset(*db_session);
        if (result != "")
        {
            ss << "SELECT Name FROM Party WHERE Id = ?", into(party), use(partyId), now;
            ss.reset(*db_session);
        }
        else
            party = "N/A";
        const char * delname = delName.c_str();
        const char * delrole = delRole.c_str();
        const char * deltitle = delTitle.c_str();
        const char * delgroup = party.c_str();
        delegates.emplace_back(deltitle, delname, delrole,delgroup);
    }
```

The vector always ends up with all instances of the object being the same as the last one emplaced onto the vector.The first value is fine, but the second addition rewrites the first and so they both become the same object, and so on.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: `.c_str()` points to the text stored in the `std::string`. All your `delegate` objects point to the same `std::string`'s data.

Comment: But why should this matter if the object has already been constructed and placed in the vector?Why would emplacing a new structure edit the ones placed beforehand?

Comment: Your members only point to a string, they do not copy it or preserve it in any way. When you change that string, all pointers to it will see the new data. This can be easily solved by making your members `std::string` instead of `const char*`.

Comment: Beware that changing a `std::string` may invalidate any previous pointer to it's data, making them unusable. It seems you got lucky (or unlucky) that the pointers were never invalidated.

Comment: So the only way to fix this is to edit the structure to use strings instead?And just pass the strings instead

Comment: You are just storing the pointer returned by `c_str`. The underlying `string` `delname`, etc. goes out of scope and you are storing dangling pointers in your `vector`. Change the class members to `std::string` instead of `const char *`.

Comment: @Max To be fair, we don't see the declaration of the `del*` strings, we don't see them go out of scope in the given example. We at least know that they are declared outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: @DanielPeedah It's not the only *possible* solution, but it's by far the easiest, cleanest and simplest.

Comment: Yes they were declared above the code I gave, I completely forgot about the consequences of using char *, as I am a fairly new programmer

Comment: @François Andrieux You are correct

Comment: You could use `strdup` if you need to keep your members as `char*`, but you do need to remember to free those pointers in your destructor and you'll also need to implement a copy constructor and assignment operator to prevent the same problem you're seeing now as well as double frees. Using `std::string` eliminates all of those issues.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use `std::string` inside your `class`.  Otherwise, you should implement a safe copy constructor that makes new copies of your character arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question invokes undefined behavior.

```
    const char * delname = delName.c_str();
    const char * delrole = delRole.c_str();
    const char * deltitle = delTitle.c_str();
    const char * delgroup = party.c_str();
    delegates.emplace_back(deltitle, delname, delrole,delgroup);
```

Look what [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) has to say about this:

> The pointer obtained from c_str() may be invalidated by:
>
> - Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
> - Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and rend().

This means that assignment operator:

```
    delTitle = record.get(0).toString();
```

invalidates `delTitle.c_str()`. This means that your `delegates` contains a bunch of invalid pointers, and dereferencing them invokes undefined behavior.

You don't get a crash because, most likely, the same internal buffer is reused for all string variations. This is pure luck, and with different strings this can be different. For example, if the strings become larger and larger with each iteration, then the buffer will get reallocated and your pointers will point to some junk.

The correct thing is to store `std::string` instead of `char *`.